# Why can't I return the password from my MERN stack app in Postman?

Tags: node.js, routes, mern

In NodeJS the 'password:' string becomes an empty string somehow. Any other string with any other name can be returned, but I cannot return the 'password'. By process of elimination I have discovered only the word 'password' becomes an empty string for some reason. I cannot return it. I cannot encrypt it. I cannot do anything to it.

This isn't just a problem with Postman because when I try to do anything with the 'password' element I get the error `[0] Error: Illegal arguments: undefined, string` in Node.
When I do a post to the route with Postman I get no response with the code below.

[image]

If I change the line `res.json(newUser.password)` in the routes file below to `res.json(newUser.email)` the route returns the email.

I am following along with a video [here](https://youtu.be/USaB1adUHM0?t=1170). It is set to jump to the time in question if you click on the link. It was filmed thirteen months after making this post, so maybe something changed to protect passwords.

At first I was trying to encrypt the password but I have discovered it is just an empty string. Has it been encrypted somewhere?

In my routes folder

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')

const path = require('path');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const MongoClient = require('mongoose');
const multer = require('multer');
const GridFsStorage = require('multer-gridfs-storage');
const Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
const config = require('config');

// Mongo URI
const mongoURI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/fuzz';

// Create mongo connection
const conn = MongoClient.createConnection(mongoURI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true });

const User = require('../../models/User')
// Init gfs
let gfs;

conn.once('open', () => {
  // Init stream
  gfs = Grid(conn.db, MongoClient.mongo);
  gfs.collection('zoo');
});

// Create storage engine
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: mongoURI,
  file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        const filename = buf.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname);
        const fileInfo = {
          filename: filename,
          bucketName: 'zoo'
        };
        resolve(fileInfo);
      });
    });
  }
});
const upload = multer({ storage });

// @route POST api/users
// @desc Register new user
// @access Public
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, password } = req.body;

  // Simple Validation
  if(!name || !email || !password) {
    return res.status(400).json({msg: 'Please enter all fields' });
  }

  // Check for existing user
  User.findOne({ email })
    .then(user => {
      if(user) return res.status(400).json({msg: 'User already exists'})

      const newUser = new User({
        name,
        email,
        password
      });
      res.json(newUser.password)

    })
});
module.exports = router;
```

The model for the route above

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  register_date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);
```

Comment: can you add User save function here

Comment: 'save function'. Sorry, I don't know what that is.